# Shape does not not return back when exceeding the border of a frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I set a condition that will not allow an oval shape to go further the limit width of a frame. For example when the x coordinate of oval shape exceeded the 500 width of a frame, the oval shape will move backward. But in my program nothing's happen the shape still moves beyond the set limit width. Can someone please check my code. Thank you.

```
 package movingball;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MovingBall extends JPanel{

    private int ballX = 30;
    private int ballY = 30;

    public MovingBall(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public MovingBall(int x, int y){
        x = this.ballX;
        y = this.ballY;  
        repaint();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,700);

        MovingBall movingBall = new MovingBall();
        frame.add(movingBall);       
        frame.setVisible(true);

        BallUsingThread ball =  new BallUsingThread(movingBall);
        Thread first = new Thread(ball);

        first.start();

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics canvas){
        super.paintComponent(canvas);

        canvas.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 100, 100);
    }

    public void animateBall(){
        boolean horizontalBoundary = true;
        boolean verticalBoundary = true;

        if(horizontalBoundary){

            ballX += 30;
            if((ballX +100 >= 500)){
                ballX -= 100;
                //horizontalBoundary = false;

            }                
        }
        if(horizontalBoundary == false){
//            if(ballX + 100 <= 0 ){
//                horizontalBoundary = true;
//            }
            ballX -= 30;
        }

        repaint();
    }

}
class BallUsingThread implements Runnable{

    private final MovingBall movingBall;
    public BallUsingThread(MovingBall mb){
       movingBall = mb;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(;;){
            movingBall.animateBall();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.printf("Error",ex);
            }
        }      
    }   
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Jay Gorio I don't see any codes which makes your ball move backwards. It is better if you show more codes.

Comment: @user3437460 Okay I updated my code and included all. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact solution, based on what you provided, but i have some guesses:

## the location of the booleans

You use a couple  of booleans in your code.
At this moment, these booleans are created in the method, so every time you call the method, they are set to true. This means that the first if-statement is always excecuted and the ball will always move further right, in this if.

## second check

In you check, when the ball is going left, you are checking if the ball has left the screen <= instead of reached the boundary >=

## repaint

On this moment, I guessed about the method, because I don't know what the repaint method is doing, maybe the error is in there?

### little remarks

`if(horizontalBoundary == false)` is equal to `if(!horizontalBoundary)`
which can be more readable.

In `if((ballX +100 >= 500))` you can remove the brackets: `if(ballX +100 >= 500)`

If you want to use an if-statement only to set a boolean variable, you can do this shorter: `horizontalBoundary = (ballX + 100 <= 0 );`

Comment: I updated my code kindly check it again. I like your suggestions.

Comment: as I suggested in the first alinea, extract the boolean variables to fields. then it works (when you uncomment the part you commented.

Comment: Sorry but mine is not working. Can you please show examle where I put those lines.